# How to include a Pause, Continue button in a Flash demo using Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5

We are making a flash demo of a website using Actionscript. Can someone help here with the help of examples/tutorials or give some tips etc.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more useful resources on the web involving buttons in as 3.0:
http://www.csupomona.edu/~llsoe/42101/Flash/AS3buttons.htm

Basically it's really simple:

1. Put a keyframe on the frame you want the movie to begin playing
2. Draw a shape and convert it to a button
3. Go into the button code and say: gotoAndPlay("keyframenumber");
4. Put a keyframe where you want the movie to end and say: stop();

Or if you just want to go to a keyframe without playing the movie use: gotoAndStop("nr");

Hope this helps you somewhat in your journey of understanding AS 3.0